# Creating word frequency pairs, keeping both words and both frequencies

Tags: python, nlp, word-frequency

I have a list of word pairs in Icelandic that are spelled similarly but mean different things (for example leyti and leiti, kyrkja and kirkja). The list is just a single element list, not a list of tuples (so just [leyti, leiti, kyrkja, kirkja]). I'm using a big corpus to get each word's frequency, so I could end up with for example leyti = frequency 3000, leiti = frequency 500 etc. I want to keep these pairs while getting the frequency from the corpus. At the moment I'm iterating through the list of words and comparing each word to the frequency list I have from the big corpus, which results in a dictionary of f.ex. {leyti: 3000, leiti:500} etc. So basically I'm doing this:

```
def findfreq():
    freqdic = findfreq() # a dictionary with all the words in the corpus and their frequencies
    ywords = listofwords() # the list of words 
    yfreq = {} # resulting dictionary with the word from the wordlist and it's frequency as it is in the corpus
    for i in ywords:
        for key, value in freqdic.items():
            if i == key:
                yfreq[i] = value
    return yfreq
```

But I don't want just a dictionary with all the words separately, I want something (tuple?) that represents the pair with both frequencies (so for example: (leyti:3000, leiti:500), (kyrkja:400, kirkja:600)). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Even with your current solution, you don't need to iterate over the entire `freqdic` every time, you want one value from it. You can just do:

```py
for i in ywords:
    yfreq[i] = freqdic[i]
```

If you want to have the words together with their frequencies in tuples, you can simply do something like this:

```py
def findfreq():
    freqdic = findfreq()
    ywords = listofwords()
    return [(w, freqdic[w]) for w in ywords]
```

You thing that addressing the tuple with index would be too cluttered, you can use `namedtuple`:

```py
from collections import namedtuple
Word = namedtuple('Word', ['form', 'frequency'])

def findfreq():
    freqdic = findfreq()
    return [Word(w, freqdic[w]) for w in listofwords()]
```

You can then access the fields with the dot notation as `w.form` and `w.frequency`.

Comment: :-) If you think the answer, please, mark it as accepted, so other people reading the post know it was a correct answer.